# Скрывается меню при прокрутке на телефоне

Tags: javascript, css, меню

При просмотре сайта pravschool-angarsk.ru с мобильного телефона, если раскрыть меню и далее подменю - приходится прокручивать из-за большого количества пунктов. Но при прокрутке меню исчезает. Как сделать в js или css, чтобы меню не скрывалось само?

Answer (score 0):

Скрывается вот тут

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Срабатывает этот код при ресайзе страницы. У современных мобильных браузеров появление/скрытие верхней панели так же стартует событие ресайз. Поэтому при старте прокрутки и пропадает меню.

Решается подобным хаком

```js
var resized = false;
$(window).resize(function(event) {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    // Запрещаем выполнение скриптов при смене только высоты вьюпорта (фикс для скролла в IOS и Android >=v.5)
    if (resized == windowWidth) { return; }
    resized = windowWidth;

    // Тут функция которую нужно запустить при смене только ширины окна
});
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!